# How to update URL-path in Angular file-upload module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

Here is a module, that I use for my project https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload
It works fine, if I'm adding URL when it create.
But, if I need to change that url after some time (before image was uploaded, but after it was initialized) - it's does not work.
See code

```
$scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: '/default_url/' //set default url
});
$scope.changeURL = function(){
    // I thougth it should work, but not
    $scope.uploader.url = '/new_cool_url/';

    //recomended way from FAQ
    $scope.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem(function(item) {
        item.url = '/new_cool_url/';
    } );

    $scope.uploader.uploadAll(); // uploading to default_url
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Take onBeforeUploadItem out from the changeURL function. Do something like this:

```
$scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: '/default_url/' //set default url
});

$scope.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem(function(item) {
    item.url = '/new_cool_url/';
} );
```